# Set MaxAllowedContentLength/maxRequestLength value per action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

How do I set maxAllowedContentLength value per action?

I have a few actions that used to upload files, each one needs a different maxAllowedContentLength value.

It make sense that we don't want to use action filters as we want to filter this request at IIS level. On the other hand, action filter is the best solution from coding perspective, as they coming **after** the routes, so I the routes change, it continue work.

In IIS6 I know we can use `<location>` tag to specify `maxRequestLength` to a specific location.
I don't know how to use this approach on IIS7, and I don't like this approach, since the url routes are hand coded in the web.config.

What is the best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Too bad this one has never been answered - it's a very important subject when programming file upload pages with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to achieve that, and I don't think that there is. Probably the best thing to do is to use a different IIS Website for the file download actions, with custom web.config.

Comment: There must be a way.. :) Most likely, you should be able to use reflection and hack into the .net runtime and modify the config. Not easy, but it should work?

(I've done similar things in the past, for syncing auth keys among others between applications.)

Comment: @Onkelborg want to give a detailed answer about this? than I'll be able to accept it as answer...

Comment: I've dug into the framework with the help of ILSpy and dug around a bit. I think the easiest way would be to rewrite the web.config and then accept that the application will restart one time. However, it seems like it's doable to rewrite in-memory at runtime, but it's quite fiddly.

I don't think you are able to have a different maxAllowedContentLength  per location, but you can have a different maxRequestLength per location.

Comment: Your best bet is to edit the web.config and accept the restart. Personally, I wouldn't fiddle with changing this type of configuration at runtime, although it's possible. My investigation says it's a quite complicated process to get everything right, and what do you know, things might change in the future

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate virtual site for the area you want different filtering.

Then run this command on your IIS server. (replace [IISWebsitename])

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "[IISWebsitename]" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:100000000 -commitpath:apphost
```

That enables 100,000,000 bytes of upload data at a time for that one web site.

Comment: I don't like using the Command-Line. But if I'm already using a different site, that I can use the Web.config to set the maxAllowedContentLength.